# Saving Django Form With Foreign Key Reference

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a form which references three models and I want to save the items to each model. One of the models has foreign key references to the other models and I want to save them too.

My models look like:

```
class Address(models.Model):
    housenumber = models.CharField(max_length=20,default='',blank=True)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=80,default='',blank=True)
    town = models.CharField(max_length=80,default='',blank=True)
    county = models.CharField(max_length=60,default='',blank=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=20,default='',blank=True)
    postcode = models.CharField(max_length=10,default='',blank=True)

class GeoLocation(models.Model):
    longitude = models.FloatField(default=-4.2576300)
    latitude = models.FloatField(default=55.8651500)

class Location(models.Model):
    locationname = models.CharField(max_length=80,default='',blank=True)
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    geolocation = models.ForeignKey(GeoLocation, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='')
```

My views looks like:

```
        if locationform.is_valid() and addressform.is_valid() and geolocationform.is_valid():
            locationform.save(commit=False)
            new_address = addressform.save()
            new_geolocation = geolocationform.save()
            locationform.address = new_address
            locationform.geolocation = new_geolocation
            locationform.save()
```

This will give me an error that states "NOT NULL constraint failed: location_location.address_id".

Can anyone help? I am new to Django so find this stuff hard.

Comment: try ``null = True`` in ``adress`` field from Location model

Comment: Thanks, this is useful for future reference, but in this case I didn't want it to be null.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Eduardo I managed to get it working with the following code, almost the same as yours:

```
    if locationform.is_valid() and addressform.is_valid() and geolocationform.is_valid():
        new_location = locationform.save(commit=False)
        new_address = addressform.save()
        new_geolocation = geolocationform.save()
        Location.objects.create(
            locationname= new_location.locationname,
            address=new_address,
            geolocation=new_geolocation)
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be:

```
if locationform.is_valid() and addressform.is_valid() and geolocationform.is_valid():
        new_address = addressform.save()
        new_geolocation = geolocationform.save()
        locationform.address = new_address
        locationform.geolocation = new_geolocation
        Location.objects.create(
            locationname=locationform.data.get('locationname', " ",
            address=new_address,
            geolocation=new_geolocation)
```

Comment: THanks from this I managed to get it working, I've posted above.